# Is it not possible to have sampling rate above 1 megahertz in apps for android?

Tags: android, android-studio, frequency

So, basically I am a little more than a beginner in android development. Currently, I am working on an app that can generate different sound frequencies to repel different animals.

The basic idea is that, animals can hear and respond to different frequencies, dogs and cats respond to frequency range 22-25kHz, Rats respond to 60-72kHz, similarly insects (38-44kHz) and lizards (52-60kHz).

The code I am using is given below but the problem is when I set sample rate (sr) to 44100 as is recommended sampling rate for humans, the app compiles and works fine but for animals I need to set the sample rate (sr) to twice of frequency i.e. sample rate 120kHz is required for generating frequency of 60kHz (to repel rats and mice). When I set such a high sample rate, the app crashed and won't run.

I don't know what is wrong. Take a look at the code.

````
package pk.edu.muet.tl.afm;

import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Animal extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button lizard;
    Button petAnimal;
    Button insects;
    Button rats;

    Thread t;
    int sr = 44100;
    boolean isRunning = true;
    double sliderval = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animal);

        lizard=(Button)findViewById(R.id.lizard);
        petAnimal=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pet_animal);
        insects=(Button)findViewById(R.id.insects);
        rats=(Button)findViewById(R.id.rats);

        lizard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                lizard.setText("Stop");
            }
        });

        petAnimal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                sliderval=22000;
            }
        });

        insects.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                sliderval=38000;
            }
        });

        rats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                sliderval=60000;
            }
        });

        t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

                int buffsize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sr, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

                AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sr, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffsize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                short samples[] = new short[buffsize];
                int amp = 10000;
                double twopi = 8.*Math.atan(1.);
                double fr = 440.f;
                double ph = 0.0;

                audioTrack.play();

                while(isRunning){
                    fr = sliderval;
                    for(int i=0; i < buffsize; i++){
                        samples[i] = (short) (amp*Math.sin(ph));
                        ph += twopi*fr/sr;
                    }
                    audioTrack.write(samples, 0, buffsize);
                }
                audioTrack.stop();
                audioTrack.release();
            }
        };
        t.start();
    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.animal, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        isRunning = false;
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t = null;
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Can you please provide the Log error output

Comment: The hardware may be incapable of such a high frequency. Not only the "sound card" circuit, but the speaker may be physically incapable of producing that frequency.